# $n$-functors between $n$-categories and compositions of $1$-morphisms

Tags: category-theory, functors, higher-category-theory

I have some questions about $2$-functors between two $2$-categories
and their compatibility with compositions. Also how the stuff
extends to $n$-functors between $n$-categories.

Recall that for usual categories $C, D$ a functor $F: C \to D$ respects
the compositions and identities: Let $X,Y, Z \in C$ and
$f: X \to Y, g: Y \to Z$ in $C$. Then $F(id_X)=id_{F(X)}$ and
$F(g \circ f) =F(g) \circ F(f)$ as proper equalities.

If if $C$ and $D$ are now $2$-categories, then a $2$-functor
$F: C\to D$ consisits of

- a set map $F: Ob(C) \to Ob(D)$
  -for each pair $c, d \in Ob(C) $ the
  $F_{c,d}:Hom_C(c,d) \to Hom_D(Fc,Fd)$ is a usual functor
  -"weak composition": Let $f: c \to d, g: d \to e$ in $C$,
  then in general $F(g \circ f) \neq F(g) \circ F(f)$ in $Hom_D(Fc, Fe)$,
  but we require only $F(g \circ f)  \cong F(g) \circ F(f)$.

And I'm intersted in precise meaning of this "$\cong$".

First of all this means that $F(g \circ f)$ and $F(g) \circ F(f)$
are isomorphic in "weak" sense. What I understood is that this "weak"
means that there exist two $2$-morphisms
$a: F(g \circ f)  \to F(g) \circ F(f)$ and
$b: F(g) \circ F(f) \to F(g \circ f)$ with
$a \circ b = id_{F(g) \circ F(f)}$ and
$b \circ a = id_{F(g \circ f)}$.

If I understood this correctly then then the last identities are proper.
The argument why these identities are proper now and not on the level
of "weak" isomorphisms seems to be that that $2$-categories are
sectretly assumed to be special $\infty$-categories where all
$k$-morphisms with $k > 2$ are identities.

My first question is if the reason I tried to explaned before that
$a \circ b = id_{F(g) \circ F(f)}$ and
$b \circ a = id_{F(g \circ f)}$ should hold as proper identities
and not just as "weak" isomorphisms is the correct one?

The next question is how the same question on compatibility
of $F(g \circ f) $ and $F(g) \circ F(f)$ generlizes to $n$-functor
between $n$-categories $C, D$ with $n >2$.

My naive guess is: First if $C,D$ are $n$-categories
and $F: C \to D$ is $n$-functor then we require again $F$ to be a
set map $F: Ob(C) \to Ob(D)$ and for each pair
$c, d \in Ob(C) $ the
$F_{c,d}:Hom_C(c,d) \to Hom_D(Fc,Fd)$ is a $(n-1)$-functor
between $(n-1)$-categories $Hom_C(c,d) $ and $Hom_D(Fc,Fd)$ by
recursion.

Now the question is what about the relation between
$F(g \circ f)  $ and $ F(g) \circ F(f)$. It seems naturally also
to require $F(g \circ f)  \cong F(g) \circ F(f)$ as isomorphisms
in weak sense, is it correct?

If that's what I wrote before make sense then the question
is how the "$\cong $" in here defined and how it difers from
the case of $2$-functor?

Can it be explaned as follows:
$F(g \circ f)  \cong F(g) \circ F(f)$ is $1$-morphisms means
that there exist again two $2$-morphisms
$a: F(g \circ f)  \to F(g) \circ F(f)$ and
$b: F(g) \circ F(f) \to F(g \circ f)$ but now we require
$a \circ b \cong id_{F(g) \circ F(f)}$ and
$b \circ a \cong id_{F(g \circ f)}$.

And now we play the same game, that
is there exist for $a \circ b$ and $ id_{F(g) \circ F(f)}$
two $3$-morphisms $a_1: a \circ b \to id_{F(g) \circ F(f)}$
and $a_2: id_{F(g) \circ F(f)} \to a \circ b$  with $a_1 \circ a_2 \cong id_{id_{F(g) \circ F(f)}}$ and $a_2 \circ a_1 \cong id_{a \circ b}$.

Similary for $b \circ a $ and $ id_{F(g \circ f)}$ and so on
and so on. And we do it $n-1$ times. Then since we are working
with $n$-categories after $n-1$-steps the "$\circ $" become
finally equalities "$=$".

The last question is if that's exactly what "$\cong $" or
"weak" isomorphism is in context of $n$-categories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an $\infty$-category, you can define an equivalence $f:a\simeq b$ to be a morphism such that there exists a morphism $g:b\to a$ and equivalences $1_a\simeq g\circ f$ and $f\circ g\simeq 1_b$. This coinductive definition unfolds into an infinite tower of higher and higher witnesses to equivalence. If we’re in a 2-category, then since all $n$-morphisms are identities for $n>2$, the tower collapses and a 2-morphism is an equivalence if and only if it’s an isomorphism in the hom-1-categories, just as you describe. The situation is entirely analogous for larger $n$.

As a remark, a 2-functor does not involve just any isomorphisms showing it respects composition, but isomorphisms respecting coherence conditions. These coherence conditions are both very important and become unmanageable to write down explicitly beyond $n=3$.

Comment: Hello Kevin, firstly thank you for this enlightening answer which definitely answers as concerns of my question! I have a short question about your remark. You used the words "coherence conditions". I stumbled a couple of times over this terminology but nowhere found a precise formulation explaning what a 'coherence condition' in higher category theory explicitely mean. Could you loose a couple of words on a brief explanation of this terminology (if there exist a precise definition of it)? I give a source where it is precisely defined?

Comment: There's not really a precise definition, but an example of a coherence condition is the pentagon axiom for the associators in a 2-category. It's anything that says "these two guys are isomorphic, in some nice way."

Comment: So it's a colection of diagrams like this guy (https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Associativity_pentagon) 
which reflects'pentagon axioms'. Let cosider this diagram as archetypical example of some phenomena
which can occure in coherence.
We have firstly diverse morphisms 
like $a(w,x,y) *z: ((w * x) *y) *z \to (w *(x*y))*z$ where $a$ is the associator. I recognize two messages
from this diagram: firstly, that all morphisms like $a(w,x,y) *z$ have to be "weak" isomorphisms in the
sense you described in your first sense of the answer. And secoundly, we have to deal with the commutativity.

Comment: The commutativity
is again meant in "weak" sense, right. That is if we assume all morphisms like $a(w,x,y) *z$
in the diagram are all $n$-morphisms, then the commutativity conditions in this case says that 
there exist a $n+1$ morphism between the two arrow compositions. The question is what is this
$n+1$ morphism? Is it only a $n+1$ morphism, or is it moreover an *isomorphism* in weak sense 
(so again like in your first sentence with $\infty$ categories)?

Comment: @IsaktheXI It should again be an equivalence in the sense I defined (it's easier to keep things straight if we call it an equivalence, rather than an "isomorphism in the weak sense", in my opinion.) But note that in a 2-category, again, every 3-morphism is an identity, so that the pentagon literally commutes. In a 3-category or higher, we have a *pentagonator*, that is, a 3-morphism filling the pentagon which is an equivalence, and there are further coherence conditions relating the pentagonators! You can see an infinite family of coherence conditions by looking into the associahedra.

Comment: so generally if we have say proper $\infty$-category and a diagram which have $n$-morphism as arrows then the commutativity is presesely a $n+1$-morphism which is an "isomorphism" in this higher categetical sense, ie a equivalence, that's the point?